# How to log in or get access to Sitecore CDP instance?

Tags: login, cdp

I am new to Sitecore CDP. Where can I find the official documentation to help me learning it and guide on how to get access & log in to a Sitecore CDP instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the official documentation for CDP and Personalize over on the Docs site: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/

General Sitecore CDP resources for developers can be found on the Developer Portal here: https://developers.sitecore.com/customer-data-management/cdp

For your specific question about logging in, there are Sitecore CDP docs on doing a [Log in to Sitecore CDP](https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-cdp/log-in-to-sitecore-cdp.html). They have these instructions:

> 1. If this is your first time accessing the Sitecore CDP, you'll receive an email from inviting you to join the account. If you haven't
>    received an email, request access from your Sitecore CDP Administrator
>    with the Enterprise Admin role. If you've logged into the Sitecore CDP
>    app before, proceed to Step 6.
> 2. Open the invitation email.
> 3. Click the Get Started button. The Sign up screen displays.
> 4. Complete the following fields:
>
>    - **Full name:** Enter your first and last name.
>    - **New password:** Enter the password you want to associate with
>      this account. Your password must be at least 10 characters with at
>      least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one number.
>    - **Confirm new password:** Re-enter the password you want to
>      associate with this account.
> 5. Click the Sign up button.
> 6. The Login screen displays.
> 7. Enter your email address in the first field.
> 8. Select the Remember Me checkbox to save your username and password the next time you login.
> 9. Click the Next button. The password field displays if you entered the correct email address associated with your account.
> 10. Enter the password associated with your account, as shown in the following image. Your password must be at least 10 characters with at
>     least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, and one number.
> 11. Click the Login button. The Sitecore CDP homepage displays.

Answer (score -3):

Well to answer it shortly, someone typically needs to invite you into an instance of Sitecore CDP.

**New instance for Sitecore Partners Specific process:**

1. Complete Sitecore CDP training from the Sitecore Elearning portal. (You will receive a certificate of completion)
2. Send an Email to “PartnerEnablement@sitecore.com” along with a certificate of completion. Sitecore can then give you access to the Sitecore Sandbox environment or dedicated instance for your organization.

**Existing Instance process:**

1. If you know your team/organization already has it, reach out to one of the admins of instance to send an invite to your email.

Disclosure: The information is from the user's own blog:
[Source](https://connectmadhavjoshi.wordpress.com/2022/01/03/how-to-login-into-cdp-instance)

Comment: Since the link directs your blog, would perhaps been more helpful to the community for all the same content to be here in the answer on SSE.

Comment: @MichaelWest Yes I Know it redirects to the blog but the blog just has extra screenshots of how can administrator invite someone, so thought I would just provide the main overview